# An error has occurred during web site deployment in App Service Editor

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, kudu

I made some changes in the QnAMakerBasDialog.cs file, in trying to edit the default threshold. I did not change any other thing. When I tried deploying my changes at first, I was not getting the expected response and so I went back the editor to reverse my changes. It was at this point I started getting this error message.

I need help in reversing all changes if possible but most expecially in getting "test web chart" and all my channels working again.

Please see error message error:

***kindly note that I tried this in the kudu console but still got the same error message***

```
\> build.cmd
        1 file(s) copied.
Installing Kudu Sync
D:\local\AppData\npm\kudusync -> D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\kudusync\bin\kudusync
+ kudusync@0.3.0
added 7 packages from 8 contributors in 3.22s
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
Failed to add 'D:\local\UserProfile\.dotnet\tools' to the PATH environment variable. Add this directory to your PATH to use tools installed with 'dotnet tool install'.

Welcome to .NET Core 3.1!
---------------------
SDK Version: 3.1.301

Telemetry
---------
The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. The data is anonymous. It is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.

Read more about .NET Core CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry

----------------
Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core
Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new
Learn about the installed HTTPS developer cert: https://aka.ms/aspnet-core-https
Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs
Write your first app: https://aka.ms/first-net-core-app
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClassCore(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClass(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String[] commandLine)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Main(String[] args)
MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClassCore(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClass(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String[] commandLine)
Failed exitCode=-532462766, command=dotnet restore "QnABot.sln"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Comment: Were your changes deployed successfully the first time? What is your deployment destination? Need some more context here

Comment: Yes they were deployed the first time. I am trying to deploy to a web app bot (if this helps) Now I am getting this error 

Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClassCore(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClass(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String[] commandLine)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Main(String[] args)

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595408/error-access-is-denied-deployment-to-azure-app-services/62597620#62597620?newreg=a59e0b6120a54e749235c7101a695bf6

Answer (score -1):

Surprisingly, I also encountered this problem. I also encountered this problem in Buid after modifying the Azure Bot code!
Even with this error, my build is successful