# Azure Function V2 dotnet signalr and cosmos exceptions

Tags: signalr, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I had azure signalR functions triggered with cosmosdb, they were running fine till yesterday. I started to have issues when installing nuget packages on new functions. After some search [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595408/error-access-is-denied-deployment-to-azure-app-services). SignalR negotioan funtion also stopped working and started to return 404.

I had 1.1.14, 2.1.515, 2.2109, and 3.1.301 dotnet versions intalled.

1. I choosed 2.2.109 in glolbal.json file. Msbuild access exception resolved. SignalR negotion function works with this dotnet sdk. Cosmos trigger functions also work standalone. However when I combine cosmos input with signalR output function stops working and I start to the following expection.

`warning CS1701: Assuming assembly reference 'System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' used by 'Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core' matches identity 'System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' of 'System.Linq.Expressions', you may need to supply runtime policy`

1. If I choose 3.1.301 sdk version in global.json cosmos input only functions work. But when I add signalR binding it starts to give the error below

`error CS0009: Metadata file 'D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.8\System.Private.CoreLib.dll' could not be opened -- Access to the path is denied.`

Azure function version is 2.0.
I am using azure webportal to add/edit function.

Any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see if you have this issue resolved. Please take a look at your [App settings reference for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings) where your [FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functions_extension_version) and [FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functions_v2_compatibility_mode) need to be set to support 3x and 2x. Please also take a look at: [Azure Functions runtime versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions) to ensure configuration is correct.

`FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~3`

`FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE = true`

Regards,
Mike

- **Reference:** [Visual Studio runtime versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#visual-studio-runtime-versions)
- **Reference:** [Changing version of apps in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#changing-version-of-apps-in-azure)
- **Reference:** [Migrating from 2.x to 3.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#migrating-from-2x-to-3x)