# How do I resolve Access Denied error when trying to deploy Echobot in Azure?

Tags: azure, bots, kudu

I had a operating bot that I tried to push an update to and got a failure response. I tried building and deploying in Kudu with no luck either. Just as a sanity check I also made a brand new echobot on Azure and tried to run the build and deploy commands in Kudu Console.

EDIT: Meant to mention I've seen a few other mentions of similar issues including:
[Error - Access is denied - deployment to Azure App Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595408/error-access-is-denied-deployment-to-azure-app-services)
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3177
https://medium.com/rare-crew/hot-issue-on-azure-and-deployment-of-apps-by-kudu-scripts-dotnet-sdk-v3-1-301-92d6e336756a

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1025:Unhandled exception. An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClassCore(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClass(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String[] commandLine)
 System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClassCore(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.set_PriorityClass(ProcessPriorityClass value)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String[] commandLine)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Main(String[] args)
Failed exitCode=-532462766, command=dotnet restore "EchoBot.sln"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Answer (score 1):

We arrived at an answer in this thread: [Microsoft Help Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/43392/how-do-i-resolve-access-denied-error-when-trying-t.html?childToView=43536#comment-43536)

For the default Echobot project generated by Azure you need a global.json file in "D:\home\site\wwwroot" with the following code. You can get to this folder by using the Kudu debug console.

```
{
 "sdk": {
 "version": "3.1.202"
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is  recently introduced by latest dotnet sdk (2.1.515 and 3.1.301) versions. This impacts the projects with custom deployment script still using dotnet restore and publish to build.Could you please try the below workaround in deploy.cmd to fix it.

SET MSBUILD_PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild-16.4\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe

call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" -t:Restore "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\my-solution.sln"

call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" -t:Publish "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\vstar-next\my-proj.csproj" -p:OutputPath="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -p:Configuration=Dev

Comment: Posted resulting output here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/43392/how-do-i-resolve-access-denied-error-when-trying-t.html