# Error - Access is denied - deployment to Azure Registration App Services

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, deployment, kudu

I tried to alter the dotnet version with the global.json. However, when i run `az webappyment source config-zip --resource-group ...`

i still get

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Vag\\Dropbox\\OTHER\\M HCI\\thesis\\4. tutorial and import data\\14.nlp-with-dispa
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-yccaebu4\knack\cli.py", line 233, in invoke
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to access the file that is stored under the user's directory "Vag" (C:\Users\Vag)

In Windows, you will not be able access the other user's directory unless you **explicitly** run the process with elevated Admin Privileges. You can either run the terminal with "Run as Administrator" or copy to non-user directory

Comment: Even with admin Privileges the result is the same. My issues relates with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760206/how-do-i-resolve-access-denied-error-when-trying-to-deploy-echobot-in-azure