# Unable to complete Kudu deployments on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, kudu, azure-webapps

I have set up a deployment following the guidelines here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=github

The deployment was working successfully when first set up.  Today I made changes to my code for a redeploy and it stopped working.

I get the following error:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment with MSBuild16.7.0.
Access is denied.
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuilds\16.8.3\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /restore "D:\home\site\repository\myproject\myproject.Web.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:configuration=Release /p:publishurl="D:\local\Temp\8d8f7e05bbfa782"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Access is denied.\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\92.30310.5111\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

I then connected to the Kudu debug portal and attempted to run the command myself.  It failed.  Then I attempted to navigate to D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuilds\16.8.3\MSBuild\Current\Bin

That version of MSBuild is missing.  The only versions present are:

```
03/27/2021  09:33 AM    <DIR>          MSBuild-15.3.409.57025
03/27/2021  09:33 AM    <DIR>          MSBuild-15.9.21.664
03/27/2021  09:33 AM    <DIR>          MSBuild-16.4
```

How do I get 16.8.3 installed?

Answer (score 0):

Azure web app is run in a sandbox environment, and the contents of the folder under `D:/home` have read and write permissions. All other folders have read-only permissions.

Azure web app has a web environment that supports deployment in various languages, so there is no need to install the `16.8.3` version of `MSBuild`.

## For your question, I can only provide the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Check what version of your project is. Net framework, .net core 2.2 or 3.1, .net5 ?
2. Check if the `Stack settings` of your azure web app is consistent with the project.

   [image]
3. (Optional step) Set the Stack settings to .Net5, and modify any file in github, such as a new file. Check the deployment results.
4. Download your project and run it locally to see if it can run normally.
5. Create a test slot, redeploy to see if it can be deployed normally, and set the traffic to temporarily not affect your web operation. See if the problem will recur. If the problem persists, please contact Microsoft.

**Related Posts：**

[1. Error - Access is denied - deployment to Azure App Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595408/error-access-is-denied-deployment-to-azure-app-services)